# pkg_resources.get_distribution() fails when import succeeds

Tags: python, package, conda

I am testing a Python installation. I found two packages, `sqlite3` and `graph_tool`, that I am able to `import`, yet they give an `DistributionNotFound` error from `pkg_resources` (see the Console logs below).

What does `pkg_resources` do exactly, and how can it miss an installed module?

Console logs:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> import graph_tool
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("graph_tool")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'graph_tool' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

and

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("sqlite3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'sqlite3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```